# Flattening Layers in MapBox

Tags: mapbox, tilemill

In brief, I’m looking for a way to either flatten layers in MapBox, or import a MapBox project into TileMill so I can flatten it into a new tile set.

My problem is this: I’m working with StroyMapJS (a JavaScript library) and it only recognizes the base layer coming from MapBox, with no additional layers. However, I have some vector data that is a critical part of the story that I want included. My thinking is that if I can flatten or merge the layers into a new basemap I would be fine. So, I would either:

1. Do this directly in MapBox – but I can’t find a feature to do this, or
2. Import the Terrain MapBox layer into TileMill, add my vector
   data, and then export as a new set of tiles and create a new project
   from these tiles in MapBox - but I can’t figure out how to bring a
   MapBox project into TileMill.

Am I going about this the wrong way or am I mission something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> but I can’t figure out how to bring a MapBox project into TileMill.

You would export your markers & overlays as GeoJSON - this will be in the Project UI in the map editor. Then you can import that GeoJSON into TileMill as a datasource.

Comment: A GeoJSON export only gives me the vector data, which I already have as a kml. When I bring the GeoJSON from the MapBox export into TileMill there is still no MapBox Terrain base layer, there is only the generic countries outline. What I am trying to achieve is a single layer that is a composite of my vector lines and the MapBox terrain layer.

Comment: You would style the features in TileMill and upload them to Mapbox, would would make them into a tile layer, rather than GeoJSON. Then it would be simple to combine and flatten the layer with Mapbox Terrain so that on the other side, it's a single tile layer.

Comment: 'Then it would be simple to combine and flatten the layer with Mapbox Terrain'  - thats the bit I dont know how to do.